# MVC3 - User Logon and Redirected based on their role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, role

My challenge is to redirect a user to their Area based on their Role
I placed an arrow to redirect to one area but I need to place an exception to handle another area if Role is not this Role type.

How would I modify the default LogOn Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Client" });

                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: you can use `if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))` sort of thing for this.

Comment: sorry I explained wrong, was just saying if you look at the actual code I placed a visual arrow where I am redirecting user to one area... ============>

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. There were absolutely NO posts out there with this straight forward answer so feel free to repost this:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "UserRoleOne"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "AreaForUserRoleOne" });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "UserRoleTwo"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "AreaForUserRoleTwo" });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hard to believe no one else has needed this yet.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might be looking for:

```
   [Authorize(Users="Smith, Steve", Roles="Admin, PowerUser")]
```

Users : Comma-separated list of usernames that are allowed to access the action method.

Roles : Comma-separated list of role names. To Access the action method, users must be in at least one of these roles.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx